# How can I automatically mount and read from a USB drive on a Raspberry Pi in C?

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to automatically mount a USB drive on to my Raspberry Pi. Once mounted, it should then read the values within a text document and display the values to the console.

I'm having trouble working out where the mount path is or should be pointed to. From everything I've read online, I should be pointing the mount point to */mnt/usb*. However, when I try to run the code below, it is unable to mount the drive. I am however successful if I change the mount point to */media/user/* and the drive appears mounted.

But then it is unable to find the file on the drive. The drive in the file explorer shows up in */media/user/8.1 GB Volume/example.txt*. However, changing the mount point to include the 8.1 GB Volume doesn't seem to work and I receive a "bad mount" error.

What am I doing wrong? I've not had much experience with Linux or C, so it's all new to me, and I'm not sure I'm pointing things to the right places or following the correct procedure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isMounted(const char *mountPoint) {
    FILE *mountsFile = fopen("/proc/mounts", "r");
    if (mountsFile == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open /proc/mounts");
        exit(1);
    }

    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), mountsFile) != NULL) {
        if (strstr(line, mountPoint) != NULL) {
            fclose(mountsFile);
            return true;
        }
    }

    fclose(mountsFile);
    return false;
}

int main() {
    const char *mountPoint = "/media/user"; // Was pointed to "/mnt/usb" but gave mounting error
    const char *usbDevice = "/dev/sda1";
    const char *fileName = "example.txt";

    // Mount the USB drive if it is not already mounted
    if (!isMounted(mountPoint)) {
        char mountCommand[256];
        snprintf(mountCommand, sizeof(mountCommand), "sudo mount %s %s", usbDevice, mountPoint);
        system(mountCommand);
    }

    // Check if the mount was successful
    if (!isMounted(mountPoint)) {
        printf("Failed to mount the USB drive.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the file from the mounted USB drive
    char filePath[256];
    snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s/%s", mountPoint, fileName);

    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read and print the contents of the file
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    fclose(file);

    // Unmount the USB drive
    char umountCommand[256];
    snprintf(umountCommand, sizeof(umountCommand), "sudo umount %s", mountPoint);
    system(umountCommand);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Using a `char` value to check against `EOF` means you can not reliably detect the end of the file, because `EOF` is an `int` value that does not compare equal to any actual `char` value returned from `fgetc()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, could this be the reason as to why the file is not detected? I receive the  "Failed to open the file" response at the moment which is before the EOF check

Comment: If you're seeing the output from your `printf("Failed to open the file.\n");` line of code, the file open failed.  Replace `printf()` with `perror()` and you should get the reason the `fopen()` call failed.

Comment: Does `/mnt/usb` exist on the filesystem and does the user running the program have write permissions to it? `/mnt` is generally owned and only writable by `root`.

Comment: added 'perror()' and receive the "no such file or directory" error. Not sure where I'm going wrong, the path to the file is media/user/8.1 GB Volume/ example.txt.  If I try to include the 8.1GB Volume in to the mount path I receive a bad mount error and still no read. So no clue. How would I go about checking /mnt/usb exists?, super new to linux in general.